# Kernel Extension Not Loaded

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-extensions, sip, darwin

I built a self-made kernel extension (named `KAuthTest.kext`) and would like to test it out. So in a VM running macOS 10.12.3, I did the followings:

- disable SIP by running `csrutil disable` in recovery mode, and reboot.
- disable kext signing check by running `sudo nvram kext-dev-mode=1` and reboot
- give it permission: `sudo chown -R root:wheel KAuthTest.kext`

Then I load it using `sudo kextload KAuthTest.kext`.

However,

1. in the system log, I didn't see the log from its start function
2. when I run `kextstat | grep -v com.apple` to see all third party kexts, I didn't see my kernel extension.

So did I miss something? How I can successfully load this into the kernel?

Note:

1. `kextutil -n -print-diagnostics KAuthTest.kext` gives this:

   > Diagnostics for KAuthTest.kext:
   >   Code Signing Failure: code signature is invalid
   >   KAuthTest.kext appears to be loadable (including linkage for on-disk libraries).
2. I did try rebooting, but still no luck